# Обособление деепричастного оборота в конце предложения

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, деепричастный-оборот

Обычный хрестоматийный пример:

> "Он переходил улицу(,) не смотря по сторонам".

Честно говоря, не совсем согласен с поставленной запятой, поскольку вижу здесь не добавочное действие (переходил улицу и не смотрел), а оттенок основного (переходил (как?) не смотря по сторонам).

---

А вы что скажете?

Comment: Согласен с вами.

Comment: @oleedd  Ну хватит уже, вот правда, на пустом месте раздуваете проблему. Одного голого предложения здесь недостаточно, чтобы однозначно пропунктуироваться. Всё зависит от акцентов, смысла и предыдущего текста.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец У вас мудрое решение, а вот Sharon за запятую.

Comment: Sharon, oleedd, столько уделяете внимания вопросу, а плюсик ему не нарисовали...

Comment: Похожий вопрос этого же автора: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/472511

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Не думал, что что-то новое и интересное обнаружу. Теперь есть за что плюс поставить.

Comment: @oleedd , жду вашего комментария: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/473789/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%8f%d1%81%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%87%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Думаю, что опять-таки всё зависит от контекста, от того, как построено предложение и что хочет выразить автор (а вопросы "как?" или "что делая?" формально можно задать ко всем деепричастным оборотам).

Да, позиция оборота, а также речевые акценты влияют на пунктуацию.
Например, здесь, как мне кажется, обособление уместно:
*Он переходил **У**лицу, не смотря по сторонам, и чуть не попал под авт**О**бус.*
А тут я бы не поставил запятую:
*Он попал под авт**О**бус, потому что переходил улицу не смотря по сторон**А**м.*

Грамота.ру, не вдаваясь в тонкости, запятую ставит:

> [**Вопрос № 304321**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=304321)
> Они бежали не смотря по сторонам. Нужна ли запятая?
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
> Запятая перед деепричастным оборотом нужна.

> *...шел по улице, не смотря по сторонам.* [из ответа на [**Вопрос № 286040**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=286040))]

Примеры с [LIVEJOURNAL](https://metodika-rki.livejournal.com/220713.html) (тоже с запятой):

*Он всегда разговаривает, не смотря в глаза собеседнику.

Она перешла дорогу, не смотря по сторонам.

Она переходит дорогу, не смотря ни налево, ни направо.

Он часто подписывает документы, не смотря на бумагу.

Охранник часто пропускает посетителей, не смотря на их лица.*

Comment: Об образе было сказано потому, что обычно именно это обстоятельство не обособляется, в отличие от времени, условия и т.д.

Comment: *а вопросы "как?" или "что делая?" подходят ко всем случаям с деепричастными оборотами* — протестую, "как?" для обстоятельства образа действия, а "что делая?" для второго действия, вопросы разные. В вашем первом примере оборот тоже на первом плане, поскольку указывает причину того, о чём говорится во второй части простого предложения. У Розенталя не такое.

Comment: Для обособления оборота центр смысла ("первый план" у Розенталя) должен быть у глагола. А в нём информативности нет. Дальше (раз уж затронули структуру со вторым глаголом): действия должны быть однородными по смыслу, второе не должно вытекать из деепричастия: *Он шёл, не смотря по сторонам, и думал.* Здесь уже нет первого плана.

Comment: Любое деепричастие сочетает в себе признаки глагола и наречия, поэтому задавание вопросов не поможет (везде формально можно сказать и "что делая/сделав", и "как"). Просто вникаем в семантику и находим приемлемую форму (что хотим, что нужно, то и выдвигаем на первый план). У меня не вытекает из деепричастия, причина кроется в первом действии: *Он переходил и чуть не попал*. Как хочу или как требуется по тексту, так и расставляю приоритеты. Могу и оборот выдвинуть: *Он переходил улицу не смотря по сторонАм, поэтому чуть не попал под автобус.*

Comment: Вопрос "как?" очень помогает (всем советую), а вот "что делая?" общий для деепричастий, не надо. Мы проверяем наличие обстоятельства образа действия, а не наоборот. Но тогда ваш вариант нелогичный ("*причина кроется в первом действии*" — она явно в "несмотрении"). Ну ладно.

Comment: Это деепричастие какое-то вспомогательное, как "не глядя". Обособление ему не к лицу. При вашей структуре обособление не очень удачно. Надо взять удачную структуру Розенталя: *Через двор, не смотря по сторонам, шагал приземистый, коротконогий, круглоголовый человек.* Вот так удачно. **Смотрю, что деепричастиям такого типа нужно играть роль обособленных наречий, чтобы обособление было удачным.**

Comment: Да, так и получается. Меняем на наречие и делаем структуру, чтобы его обособление было удачным. Тогда всё грамотно и удачно. Во всех примерах Розенталя как обособленные наречия (когда обособлено при образе действия), там всё удачно. А ударения здесь — следствие. В этой теме не они решают.

Comment: @oleedd Из пустого в порожнее переливаем. Всё удачно! :)

Comment: Нет, здесь крайне важный момент. Меняем "не смотря по сторонам" на "невнимательно": *Он переходил улицу, невнимательно, и чуть не попал под автобус.* Удачно не звучит. Мне сразу не понравилась эта структура, вот это передаёт почему. Александр, проблема в том, что оно или образ действия, или обычное деепричастие. Что-то одно. А структура на это не влияет. Она лишь может позволить обособить обстоятельство.

Comment: С примерами LIVEJOURNAL интересно: *Он всегда разговаривает, не смотря в глаза собеседнику. Он часто подписывает документы, не смотря на бумагу. Охранник часто пропускает посетителей, не смотря на их лица.* Без оборота совсем другой смысл. В первом примере вообще ерунда получается. Следовательно, обособлять нельзя.

Comment: А вопросы, в том числе "как?", Розенталь рекомендует задавать: Деепричастие, перешедшее в наречие
или имеющее значение наречия образа действия (отвечает на вопросы: ***как? каким образом? в каком положении?***), не обособляется.

Comment: У Розенталя есть очень хороший пример с вашей структурой и обособленным образом действия: *Тарантас въехал на двор, шурша колесами по крапиве, и остановился перед крыльцом* (Тургенев). Здесь у оборота второстепенный смысл, ничего важного, существенного в нём нет. А у вас иначе. Сопоставимые примеры Розенталя: *Веретьев сидел наклонившись и похлопывал веткой по траве. Он сел на стул не раздеваясь и задумался.* То, что предложение продолжается, роли не играет. Просто чтобы все понимали.

Comment: См. комментарии под ответом Jim Korbett. Вам надо подправить.

Comment: @oleedd Что подправить? Убрать слово "логические"? Логическое ударение может совпадать с тактовым, фразовым, тоническим...

Comment: Не совсем, звучать будет по-другому. Логическое — это когда специально акцентируют слово, как сказано по ссылкам Jim Korbett, делая противопоставление или скрытое противопоставление. Например: *Он переходил Улицу [, а не что-то другое / а не то, что ты сказал].*

Answer (score 1):

1. Я согласна с ответами **Грамоты.ру**, а также считаю, что при отсутствии контекста следует выбирать вариант **с обособлением** деепричастного оборота как **основной**.  В этом случае деепричастие обозначает второе (добавочное) действие.
2. П**ри отсутствии обособления** деепричастный оборот приобретает обстоятельственное значение  наречного выражения. Ударение  переходит на конец фразы, при этом подчёркивается **значимость оборота**. Это означает необходимость развития темы, обозначенной оборотом, так как без этого  предложение  выглядит незаконченным и «неуравновешенным».

В любом случае отсутствие обособления — это **частный вариант** в теме деепричастий, требующий обоснования с точки зрения семантики.

3. **При обособлении**  оборота действие, обозначенное глаголом, является основным, а оборот обозначает второе действие. Тогда тема деепричастного оборота не требует продолжения.
4. **Примеры возможного контекста** для двух вариантов.

**Обособление**. *Наконец зажегся зеленый свет, людской поток подхватил и его. Он переходил улицу, **не смотря по сторонам.** В этот момент кто-то окликнул его, и он обернулся.*

**Нет обособления**.  *Он переходил улицу  **не смотря по сторонАм**. Такое небрежение не всегда кончается благополучно. Взвизгнули тормоза, машина едва не наехала на него.*

**Примечание**

Я прошу участников строго **соблюдать правила** относительно поведения, а также комментариев. Вы можете задать мне вопросы, уточняющий  мой ответ или предлагающий его улучшение. По этому вопросу я уже слышала все замечания и поэтому просьба  **не повторяться**.

Если вы не согласны с ответом, предложите **свой ответ**. Не переходите на личности и не используйте неуважительную лексику. Спасибо за соблюдение правил.

Мои ответы с грубым нарушением этих правил были мною удалены.

Comment: Это уже лучше. Уже можно понять точку зрения. Ревью на варианты, считаю, надо скопировать, оно объективное. Вижу разницу между вашими вариантами. Видно, что вы старались. Но вариант с запятой притянут за уши. Во-первых, там надо "перешёл". Во-вторых, так не скажут, воспринимается, как: *Наконец зажёгся зеленый свет, людской поток подхватил и его. Он переходил улицу, **небезопасно**. В этот момент кто-то окликнул его, и он обернулся.* Никто не скажет про что-то опасное так, будто это в порядке вещей и развитие этого момента не требуется.

Comment: Есть одно замечание, считайте, что предложение улучшения. Предложение незаконченное — это когда нужно поставить многоточие в связи с нехваткой слов. А в данном случае надо использовать другую терминологию.

Comment: Как вы определяете, второе действие или характеристика первого? У Розенталя это постановка вопросов ("Деепричастие, перешедшее в наречие или имеющее значение наречия образа действия (отвечает на вопросы: *как? каким образом? в каком положении?*), не обособляется"). И такой ещё вопрос: если оборот будет "*прихрамывая на правую ногу*", то будет ли решение другим?

Comment: Я оставляю за собой право отвечать на интересные для меня вопросы, а также симпатичным мне людям.  Ваши замечания мне неинтересны. И переход на личности все-таки обозначен (это уже лучше; вижу, что старались).  Ваша оценка меня тоже  не интересует. Так что ответов НЕ БУДЕТ ни сейчас, ни впоследствии.  Потому оставьте меня в покое, а то придется обратиться  к модераторам. Вы постоянно нарушаете правила форума. Если много критических замечаний, дайте свой ответ. И отвечать на вопросы в комментариях тоже не надо.

Comment: Переход на личности, это когда говорится, какой человек, например "тупой", "необразованный", "неспособный понять" (качества личности). У меня нет никакого перехода!

Comment: И не надо бояться критики, это путь к прогрессу. И к истине.

Comment: И оспаривание правильности ответа соответствует правилам. Так на всех ветках SE делают. Просто система не любит, когда много комментариев.

Comment: Оказалось, что Jim Korbett прав. См. комментарии под его ответом.

Answer (score 0):

Вы правы, в данном случае запятая не является обязательной, так как это не добавочное действие, а скорее оттенок основного действия "переходил". Правильное написание предложения без запятой: "ОН переходил улицу не смотря по сторонам".