# Поясняющий член - это определение или дополнение?

Tags: дополнение

> Я увидел крокодила, то есть аллигатора.

1)С одной стороны, я увидел (кого) аллигатора, крокодила

2)С другой стороны, я увидел крокодила (какого именно) - аллигатора.

Как все же верно?

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145658/discussion-on-question-by-ajgy------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: Вы нашли тот вопрос? Что вас там напрягало? Какая там нестыковка?

Comment: @oleedd какой тот?

Comment: За который говорю уже 3 часа. Про части речи.

Comment: Про слово "все"?

Comment: Там тоже нестыковка, да, но разве мы его обсуждали? Пока нет. Можно было бы немного. Там есть "за" и "против".

Comment: Тогда говорите прямо!

Comment: Вы уже не помните, что вы спрашивали и что мы обсуждали? Вопрос про части речи...

Comment: Не ходите вокруг да около. Говорите прямо.

Comment: Подумайте. Этот вопрос буквально перед носом.

Comment: Не знаю . Говорите

Comment: Откройте список вопросов. Хочу, чтобы вы сами разгадали. Здесь ничего сложного нет. Было недавно...

Comment: Нет. Говорите же

Comment: Я здесь диктую правила. А вы ведёте себя как начальник. Естественно, что тоже спрашивается, какая часть речи. Это как бы очевидно.

Comment: Не хотите - как хотите!

Comment: Неужели вам трудно открыть список вопросов и посмотреть, какие в начале про части речи, если вы не помните, что мы недавно обсуждали? Просто ужас.

Comment: Все на этом!!!!

Comment: Жаль, что вы сдаётесь на ровном месте. Вы буквально в самом вопросе там спрашиваете, какая часть речи...

Comment: О частях речи говорится в шапке вопроса...

Comment: Сказали бы, что у вас склероз, тогда сразу бы сказал, какой вопрос...

Comment: От вас ответа так и не получить, так что не буду даже стараться.

Comment: А в чём здесь старание? Посмотреть, какие вопросы в первой пятёрке...

Comment: Надеюсь, вы не подумали, что там вопрос о наречиях. Там о других частях речи.

Comment: И вот та разница, которую вы обнаружили (не часть речи, а разница), является здесь правильным ответом.

Comment: Ну ладно, вопрос про прилагательные и причастия.

Comment: Ответ, который вам предлагаю, похож на тот, что дала Грамота, но не такой размазанный и более научный. А вернее, очень точный. А вам дали правильный, но мазню. Не понимаю, почему вы так ненавидите загадки. Этим же учителя занимаются... И здесь давно уже всё решено, разные взгляды учёных — не про это.

Answer (score 1):

*Я увидел крокодила, **то есть аллигатора**.*

Ответить на этот вопрос несложно: ***Аллигатора*** — это член предложения, который поясняет первое дополнение (***крокодила***). Использован союз ***ТО ЕСТЬ***, но в данном случае  он имеет значение *ТОЧНЕЕ*.

Здесь пояснительный член можно считать вторым **дополнением**, но никак **не определением**. Поэтому непонятно, о чем  можно так долго говорить. Надо всего лишь хорошо разбираться **в крокодилах**))

**[Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=119#pp119)**

1. Слова, поясняющие смысл **предшествующего члена предложения**, выделяются (или отделяются) знаками препинания (запятыми, тире, двоеточием).

**Примечание.** Все ныне живущие крокодилы делятся **на три семейства:** собственно крокодилы, аллигаторы и гавиалы. По внешнему **виду** можно легко различить аллигатора и крокодила. Самое большое различие — **в их зубах**. Когда челюсти у крокодила сомкнуты, то виден большой четвертый зуб нижней челюсти. У аллигатора же верхняя челюсть закрывает эти зубы. Также их можно отличить **по форме морды:** у настоящего крокодила морда острая, V-образная, у аллигатора - тупая, U-образная.

Answer (score 0):

Зависит от контекста.
Я увидел крокодила (особь отряда крокодиломорфных), то есть аллигатора (особь семейства аллигаторовых). Тогда структура фразы: Я увидел мебель, то есть стул. Крокодил (мебель) - дополнение, аллигатор (стул) - определение. {Извините, здесь было неверно: *соответственно, тоже*} В данном случае аллигатор уточняющий член предложения.

Я увидел крокодила (особь семейства крокодиловых), то есть аллигатора (особь семейства аллигаторовых). Тогда структура фразы: Я увидел стол, то есть стул.
Крокодил (стол) - дополнение, аллигатор (стул), соответственно, тоже. Здесь аллигатор  не уточняющий и не поясняющий, а заменяющий член предложения если такие существуют. По смыслу исходному предложению будет эквивалентна фраза:
Я увидел крокодила, извините, аллигатора.